# Making Elements as composite in enterprise architect

Tags: enterprise-architect

In EA through automation if element has to be made as composite then the API is Element.SetCompositeDiagram(Diagram.DiagramGUID) So in the EA table where to find this Value set in the t_object table.

Comment: The simple answer is found below. But I guess your question is not complete?

Comment: if t_object.NType = 8 is set then the element is composite but where they are actually mapping the specific diagram GUID to element in table

Comment: I was sure you were after this. I'll amend my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A composite element is marked with

```
t_object.NType = 8
```

To complete this, you need to set

```
t_diagram.ParentID = t_object.ObjectID
```

or `Element.ElementID` of the composite element.